# C++ Struct Constructor With Arguments Separated Into Header and Implementation Files Fails When Single Monolithic File Doesn't

Tags: c++

I have seen this question asked many times, but the basic answer appears to be multiple inclusion of a header file. In my case, this is not the problem, and I don't know what is.

I have a basic c++ file that appears to work fine here:

```
// Filename : t1.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

struct T1{
    int result;

    T1(int var1, int var2) {
        result = var1 * var2;
    }
};

void main(void){
    T1 t(2, 3);
    printf("%d\n", t.result);
}
```

When compiled and run, the answer 6 is produced. Great. Now, when I split this code into two files, a .cpp and a .h, I get the error (error C2011: 'T1': 'struct' type redefinition). Here is what those two different files look like:

```
//Filename : test1.h
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

struct T1{
    int result;

    T1(int var1, int var2);
};
#endif

//Filename : test1.cpp
#include "test1.h"

struct T1{
    int result;

    T1(int var1, int var2) {
        result = var1 * var2;
    }
};
```

I've tried using #pragma once, as well as using class instead of struct, but it doesn't matter. Something is fundamentally wrong here. I don't understand why it works in the stand alone file, but not when separated into header and implementation versions. What do I need to do to the header and implementation files?

Comment: test1.cpp is redefining T1. You just want the ctor: `T1::T1(int var1, int var2) {  result = var1 * var2;  }`

Comment: "I get the error"  Please [edit] your question to show this error.  You seem to have forgotten to mention what error you are getting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `struct T1 { /* ... */ };`, you are defining the struct `T1`. A struct should only be defined once in each translation unit, generally by putting the definition into a header file and including that header file into each translation unit that needs the definition. Since `test1.cpp` includes `test1.h`, it should not attempt to define `T1` a second time.

Instead, `test1.cpp` needs to define the *function* `T1::T1`, which was declared in the definition of `T1` found in `test1.h`, but not yet defined. To define a member function outside the class definition in which the member function was declared, we use the following syntax:

```
T1::T1(int var1, int var2) {
    result = var1 * var2; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Brian. Very simple, yet fundamentally effective.

Resulting Header File:

```
 //Filename : test1.h
#pragma once

typedef struct T1{
 int result;
 T1(int var1, int var2);
}T1;
```

Resulting Implementation File:

```
//Filename : test1.cpp
#include "test1.h"

  T1::T1(int var1, int var2) {
  result = var1 * var2; 
}
```

Resulting Driver File:

```
//Filename drvr.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test1.h"

void main(void) {
 T1 t(2,3);
 printf("%d\n", t.result);
}
```

Thank you all for having a look at this, and posting solutions.